# Kinect - UBUNTU DRIVER? Using Linux Mint 21 - 'std::runtime_error' - Missing Driver?

Tags: drivers, usb

Brand new (haven’t used it since 2006) to Ubuntu, Linux & drivers or modules or kernels.

**We’re not sure how ask how to find the** kernels, or drivers or modules or what causes failure to get a Xbox One Kinect to communicate successfully with Linux Mint 21 MATE?

Attempting these instructions in Step 6 located here  [https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/SARndbox/](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Eokreylos/ResDev/SARndbox/) :

'`sudo /usr/local/bin/KinectUtil getCalib 0`'

Returns this error:

```
'Downloading factory calibration data for Kinect v2 V2-271548135047...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  USB::Device::claimInterface: Interface 1 is already claimed
Aborted'
```

So in our lack of experience, the PC sees the Kinect but gets timed out so they can’t communicate. Linux Mint 21 is built on top of Ubuntu so we think we’re posting this in the right spot.

This is the 'lsusb' results:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:4ef3 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP 310 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:2852 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 045e:02c4 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Sensor
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 045e:02d9 Microsoft Corp. NuiSensor Adaptor      
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4ef0 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP 310 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is '`lsusb -1`' results:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 20000M/x2
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/1p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```